# pass snapshot to another page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to pass snapshot data to another page but IDE give an error.

The code is:

```
TextButton(onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>reactor(snapshot:snapshot.data![i])));
                    }, child: Text("view likes"))
```

reactor.dart

```
class reactor extends StatefulWidget {
  const reactor({Key? key,required this.snapshot}) : super(key: key);
  final snapshot;
  @override
  State<reactor> createState() => _reactorState();
}
class _reactorState extends State<reactor> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
body: Center(
     child: Text(snapshot!.likes.length.toString(),)    
    );

  }
}
```

I have used Posts model class. How to pass it and thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please add your error too?

Comment: The error given by IDE is: Undefined name 'snapshot'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix it like this:

```dart
Text(widget.snapshot.likes.length.toString(),)
```

Comment: Oh ,I forgot that I have to use widget in stateFul widget.